# ManyToMany insertion issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many

### The goal

Create a new market and add its manager successfully.

### The problem

> Entity Validation Failed - errors follow:
>
> MyApp.Models.Data.Users failed validation
>
> - Email : The Email field is required.
> - PHash : The PHash field is required.
> - PSalt : The PSalt field is required.

### The scenario

I'm creating a market on my application and I can set to it a manager. In other words, I'm attaching to a market a user that already exists. I'm trying to do this by the following code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(Market market)
{
    [...]

    Market marketBasics = new Market
    {
        Name = market.Name,
        Slug = market.Slug,
        Manager = market.ManagerId
    };

    [...]

    User user = new User
    {
        Id = market.ManagerId
    };

    db.Markets.Add(marketBasics); // Here I insert all the information
                                  // into "markets" table.

    marketBasics.User.Add(user);  // Here I (attempts to) insert into 
                                  // "users_in_markets"

    [...]
}
```

As you can see, I'm not setting the user's `Email`, `PHash` or `PSalt` — I'm not registering a new user, but I'm associating an existing (user) to a (new) market.

So I ask: **How can I resolve this?**

### Technical details

I'm using Entity Framework 5 + C# + MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the answer of [Davud](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2544245/davud) and a little research, I discover that I need to attach the user's Id to the `User` entity.

Follow the final code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(Market market)
{
    [...]

    Market marketBasics = new Market
    {
        Name = market.Name,
        Slug = market.Slug,
        Manager = market.ManagerId
    };

    [...]

    User user = new User
    {
        Id = market.ManagerId
    };

    db.User.Attach(user);
    marketBasics.User.Add(user);
    db.Markets.Add(marketBasics);

    [...]
}
```

To learn more about `Attach` method, [take a look here, on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb896271%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Success for you all!

Answer (score 2):

The user is not added because you add the user to the market after the market has been added to the database. Therefore the user is not present in the market in the database.

```
    marketBasics.User.Add(user);  //First add user to market

    db.Markets.Add(marketBasics); //Then add market to database
```

I hope that helped!